# Java Programing | How can we print below output from given input

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

```
Input = 
Array [] a = {1,2,3,6,9,4};

output: 
Output 1  : need to print pair of number with square and squareroot
e.g. 2 , 4
     3 , 9

Output 2 : unpaired number : 1 and 6 for which we dont have any square root pair.
```

I am wirting below code to get output for the first part :

```
int [] sample = {9, 4 ,3 ,2, 6 , 1};

        for (int i =0 ;i <sample.length ; i++){

            int square = sample [i] * sample[i];
            double mathsq = Math.sqrt(sample[i]);

            for ( int j= 0; j< sample.length ; j ++){

                if (sample[j] == square && sample[j] != sample [i]) {
                    System.out.println(sample[i] + "==> " + sample[j]);

                }
                
            }


        }
```

unable to find login for second scenario..

Comment: Have a duplicate `Set` of all the numbers. Upon each hit of square or square root, remove those numbers from that global set.  After the outer loop is over, the remaining numbers are not hit by anything - that's your 2nd output.

Answer (score 0):

So I found the solution with below code, I created One ArrayList to store the Element has squareroot and square relation and then compare it with Existing Array.

below is the code snippet

```
public class Demo {


    public static void main(String[] args){

        int [] sample = {9, 4 ,3 ,2, 6 , 1};
        ArrayList<Integer> newarr = new ArrayList<>();


        for (int i =0 ;i <sample.length ; i++){

            int square = sample [i] * sample[i];

            for ( int j= 0; j< sample.length ; j ++){

                if (sample[j] == square && sample[j] != sample [i]) {

                    System.out.println(sample[i] + "==> " + sample[j]);

                    newarr.add(sample[i]);
                    newarr.add(square);
                }

            }

        }

        System.out.println("Unpaired : ");
        for (int i =0 ;i <sample.length ; i++) {
            if (!newarr.contains(sample[i])) {

                System.out.print(sample[i] + " , ");
            }

        }





    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the *inner-loop*, skip *j* when it's *i*.

```java
for ( int j= 0; j< sample.length ; j ++){
    if (i == j) continue;
```

And, check for *mathsq* instead of *sample [i]*.

```java
if (sample[j] == square || sample[j] == mathsq)
```

Output

```
9==> 3
4==> 2
3==> 9
2==> 4
```

If you additionally want to print the unpaired numbers, use a *boolean*.

Here is a re-factor.

```java
int [] sample = {9, 4 ,3 ,2, 6 , 1};
boolean x;
for (int i =0 ;i <sample.length ; i++){

    int square = sample [i] * sample[i];
    double mathsq = Math.sqrt(sample[i]);
    x = false;
    for ( int j= 0; j< sample.length ; j ++){
        if (i == j) continue;

        if (sample[j] == square || sample[j] == mathsq) {
            System.out.println(sample[i] + "==> " + sample[j]);
            x = true;
        }

    }
    if (!x) System.out.println(sample[i] + " unpaired");

}
```